# Sci-fi book about a boy who lives a few seconds into the future as well as the present

Tags: story-identification

The story goes like this: There's a little boy living with his dad (mom disappeared/died in some accident). The kid lives a few seconds into the future as well as the present - he answers questions even before they are asked because he lives through everything two times. So he finds it difficult to make friends. This world is so advanced and there are concepts of time weavers and such who can give birth to triplets but in different years? A lady who's a part of this time organisation comes to help this kid not phase out of reality altogether. They take this spaceship and go meet Einstein in the past to help him get the energy mass relation. They come back and the phasing of the kid gets really bad that he sees his mom who apparently disappeared due to a similar reason.

I've been wanting to know the name of this book for so long. Read it in my childhood but the story just stuck with me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Missing_(novel_series)) but I'm pretty sure it's not what you're looking for (time organisation, boy protagonist, meeting Einstein, but the other details don't seem to fit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Twilight in the Land of Nowhen](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17327883-twilight-in-the-land-of-nowhen) by Nury Vittachi.

[image: Twilight in the Land of Nowhen]

> Imagine living 3 seconds ahead of everyone else! This funny, mind-twisting, adventure for 10-14-year-olds tells you exactly what that's like - and plays with Einstein's theory of relativity along the way.

There is  detailed review here that confirms the points you mention in your question. For example:

> As the result of what had happened in space, he has been born with a glitch in his amygdala, resulting in a condition called displacement, fourth-dimensional synchronitis or time-sickness. In other words, he is three seconds ahead of everyone else in time. He answers questions before they have been asked. He reaches for things before they have been handed to him. This makes it utterly impossible for him to make friends at school; even those students who started off being friendly to him become annoyed at what they perceive as his weirdness. His teachers are also unimpressed, though he is good at his studies -- a genius, in fact. His father is too busy going out with new girlfriends and working on his souped-up flying car (this is the not-too-distant future) to be interested in Simon's troubles.

The school janitor, Mrs. Blit, helps Simon and warns him:

> She helps Simon to control his problem to a certain extent, but tells him that, firstly, it's incurable and secondly, if it gets much worse - it's already the worst she has ever seen - Simon will find himself in the condition known as Nowhen, disappearing from history altogether. He will never have been born.

The review does not mention Simon's mother other than to say:

> Simon hasn't been able to ask his mother about it; he has been raised by his father and told his mother had died.

I found this by pure dumb luck. While randomly Googling I stumbled across [this question on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/19237101-solved-science-fiction-children-s-book-about-a-boy-who-s-a-few-seconds) that asked about the same book.

Comment: Oh my God!!! Thank you so much!!